# Bootstrap, Destroys an element’s dropdown

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

> $().dropdown('dispose')   Destroys an element’s dropdown.

what does it mean?? does it mean that the tag is removed? does it mean that the tag won't work as a dropdownlist anymore?? No! When i call that method, it does NOTHING! Can anyone give me a simple example showing that method WORKING?

bootstrap documentation is SO AWFUL

Comment: Calm down, Bootstrap is open source so you should be appreciating free open source software that developers have given there spare time for free to develop and maintain.

Comment: @folder I had posted your issue here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25323 You might want to chime in there and confirm or explain it further.

Answer (score 0):

Our dispose method : clear listener and our variables that's all see : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/dropdown.js#L187